# Contact Importer in PHP (Open Inviter Technology)

Tags: php

I am using contact importer in PHP (by open inviter technology).
I am able to successfully import contacts from g-mail and hot-mail.
But I am facing some problems in yahoo and twitter.
My website url, where I am using contact importer is :

http://21flats.com/beta/contacts_importer/OpenInviter/example.php?url1=http://21flats.com/beta/projects/16/26/Own_a_villa_in_Himalayas_an_attractive_price.html&project=16

In some of yahoo mails it imports contacts successfully, but in some emails it shows error
'Login failed. Please check email and password you have provided and try again later!'

The emails from which I can import contacts successfully are  'testing_1988@ymail.com'  and 'sushilkandola1988@yahoo.com'. Both of these id's are newly created.
But some of old id's are not importing contacts e.g 'testingdeveloper@ymail.com'

And for Twitter it shows an error 'Unable to get contacts !'

Please help me for this.

Answer (score 0):

To help yourself narrow down the problem, you could try importing contacts from the old IDs that aren't working on the [CloudSponge test drive](http://www.cloudsponge.com/test-drive).

At least that will help you figure out if it's a problem with Open Inviter or a problem with those individual accounts.